# How to set current view in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a main view in my Xamarin project. That view contains a List that when I click on an element, a Details page is shown. I can back to the source view when I press back button, however, I need to go to original view programmatically.

Is there a way to do that?

Notice I don't need just to emulate back button, but to go to certain view when another view is loaded.

Any help?

Comment: How did you push to a new page in view model? I think you can pass the Navigation to view model using Dependency Injection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

[Xamarin Navigation docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)

```
Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Comment: How can I call that from a model class? I tried calling MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync() but an exception was thrown telling that it cannot be called globally... I should use NavigationPage instead.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your MainPage around NavigationPage in the App.xaml.cs and then you will have access to it.
Then you can simply make a call to a navigation.
Additionally, when you do this, you will have a navigation bar on the top, you can hide it if you don't need one.

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyPage());
```